# iframe breaks browser back button - how to fix when using Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, meteor, youtube

I've tried everything, but I can't get around this common issue where using the browser's back button navigates the iframe (*youtube*) back, but not the page (*at least, not before a couple of clicks*).

I've read and attempted several solutions, but nothing works for me. Could it be that I just don't understand how Meteor works, and that I need to place the code meant to fix the issue somewhere specific? Like Deps.autorun, or Template.mytemplate.rendered, or ... something! I can't understand how the workarounds work for other people.

Please help if you truly have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent this issue, it is better to destroy the iframe and create a new one when rendering a new Youtube video. That way, clicking the back button won't navigate the iframe back.

Comment: Great. This is the answer. I had to create a template within the route's main template to get the video to show on the initial load. Then I ran Template.mytemplate.rendered on the template, and Deps.autorun within that. Then the code to destroy, then create the iframe within Deps.autorun. Thanks a lot. I was looking for a solution for about 2 full days (sheesh). Maybe the reason I couldn't find one is that this is kind of a simple answer. You'd be surprised how many other people are letting this drive them nuts.